# Electron renderer process in setInterval cannt use ipcRenderer.send()

Tags: javascript, setinterval, electron

**Demand:**

The renderer process need send data to main process.

**My code:**

```
//index.js (renderer process)
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

class WebWindow {
  constructor() {

    ...

    setInterval(() => {
      this.foo()
    }, 2000)

    // or 

    let that = this
    setInterval(function() {
      thar.foo()
    }, 2000)


  }

  foo () {
    data = {}
    ipcRenderer.send('async-cookies', data)
  }
}
```

**Question**
I get the error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Function.eval
```

Semms cannt use ipc in setInterval ?

How can i do this..

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to play the this/that/self redeclaration game when using arrow-functions, and your code doesnt show the declaration of that?

Comment: I edited.  Both of these codes i was tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to define another function inside the class WebWindow, nor do you need to redeclare *this* inside of arrow functions.

```
//index.js (renderer process)
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

class WebWindow {
  constructor() {

    setInterval(() => {
      ipcRenderer.send('async-cookies', data)
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```